# how to check how many fields inside a div is empty?

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
 <div class="input-group require" data-require-min="1">
    <input type="text"  name="firstname" > 
    <input type="text"  name="firstname" > 
    <input type="text"  name="firstname" > 
 </div>
```

I am trying as :

```
console.log($(".input-group input:not(:empty)").length);
```

What I want to know how many input fields is empty wrapped by `.input-group` class. I can go through .each to do this. But I am searching for one line clean code. Any idea?

Comment: `:empty` selects elements that have no children, not inputs without values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use jQuery `filter`

```js
$(function() {
  let empty = $(".input-group input").filter(function() {
    return this.value.trim() === "";
  });

  console.log(empty.length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group require" data-require-min="1">
  <input type="text" name="firstname1">
  <input type="text" name="firstname2">
  <input type="text" name="firstname3" value="               ">
  <input type="text" name="firstname4" value="TEST">
</div>
```

**Note:** The expected result is 3 because it trims the value. Remove the `.trim()` if space value is counted.

Doc: [.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution which uses the [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) Array method, which straight-forwardly returns true if every input is empty. Throw in a `.trim()` or `.replace()` if you need to account for white space.

```js
function checkEmpty() {
  const inputs = $('#nameform input').toArray()
  const allEmpty = inputs.every(input => input.value === '')

  console.log("All inputs empty:", allEmpty)
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <div id="nameform" class="input-group require" data-require-min="1">
    <input type="text"  name="firstname" > 
    <input type="text"  name="firstname" > 
    <input type="text"  name="firstname" > 
 </div>
 <button onclick="checkEmpty()">Check Empty</button>
```

Comment: jquery tag only

Comment: Then replace the document methods with `$` ¯\\\_(ツ)\_/¯

Comment: Updated it anyway